# Do I have to fill my controller´s method when I use form model binding?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6, laravelcollective

I'm doing and crud. I see in videos that in the form model binding use something like this:

```
{!! Form::model($usu, ['route' => ['prurequests.update', $usu->id],'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
```

but they have the update function empty.

i wanna know if i use `prurequests.update` or `prurequests.edit` or `prurequests.store` have i to fill these methods?

do I have to specify the method in if I put .store or .edit or .update because I see on the internet that they do not use it but I don't use it I get this:

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
>   No message

in my app i have the next:

```
{!! Form::model($usu, ['route' => ['prurequests.update', $usu->id],'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
  {!! Form::label('nombre', 'Modifique el nombre') !!}
  {!! Form::text('nombre', null) !!}
  {!! Form::label('slug', 'Modifique el slug') !!}
  {!! Form::text('slug', null) !!}
  {!! Form::submit('Actualizar') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

route:

```
Route::resource('/prurequests','PruebasControllers\PrurequestsController', ['parameters' => ['prurequests' => 'usuario2']]);
```

controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {
   $usuario = Usuario2::findOrFail($id);
   $usuario->update($request->all());
   return 'datos guardados';
 }
```

I don't know if I can let my update method empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert Update and Delete is Easy When You are using laravel resource.
Check my working Example

In Edit method:

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $data['category'] = BlogCategory::find($id);
        return view('category.edit', compact(['data']));
    }
```

In view :

```
{!! Form::model($category, ['route' => ['category.update', $category->id],'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
  {!! Form::label('nombre', 'Modifique el nombre') !!}
  {!! Form::text('nombre', null) !!}
  {!! Form::label('slug', 'Modifique el slug') !!}
  {!! Form::text('slug', null) !!}
  {!! Form::submit('Actualizar') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

update method :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $data = $request->all();          
        $category = BlogCategory::find($id);
        $category->update($data);  
        return redirect(route('category.index'));
    }
```